# Remove Records in BigQuery Table By Partition Metadata?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, partitioning

Coming across an issue and wondering if anyone would be able to help. There is a designated table in our BQ project that hosts sales `myproject_dataset.sales_table`. This table is not partitioned by `_PARTITIONTIME` but by the date identifier in the sales files, `Sales_Date` so I'm unable to query data in this table by day it was ingested but by date in the Sales file.

There was a file loaded into `myproject_dataset.sales_table` table with incorrect data for a particular date, ex. 2022-10-19. The issue is this file also contains records from previous dates as well, so executing the following command to remove the incorrect data won't solve the issue:

> DELETE from `myproject_dataset.sales_table`
> WHERE `Sales_Date` = 2022-10-19"

I queried using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS` to get the `partition_ID` of the incorrect file loaded into `myproject_dataset.sales_table` on the particular date, ex. 2022-10-19.

Is there a way to delete records by partition metadata, ex. `partition_ID` in a BQ table?

I queried using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS to get the table metadata, particularly the partition_ID of the incorrect file loaded into myproject_dataset.sales_table on the particular date, ex. 2022-10-19.

Comment: What's the type of partitioning? Normally, it's date, on a field or on pseudo column _PARTITIONDATE, or it's an integer (with range bucket). In your case, I don't understand your blocker

Comment: The table is partitioned by the date in the Sales Files received (ex. Sales_Date). I want to delete records for a file ingested on a particular date (ex. 2022-10-19). This file has records from dates outside of 2022-10-19 included, however, so I'm looking for a way to delete all records from this file ingested on 2022-10-19 if the pseudo column _PARTITIONTIME isn't available.

Comment: If you haven't a reference to that ingestion date or the origin file, you can't find the related data. One solution to solve that (in the future) is to have an ingestion date (or other ingestion metadata like the filename). the column default value feature in bigquery is an easy way to achieve that: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/default-values

Comment: The file name is not loaded into the sales_table but I have the partition_ID that references the file's particular ingestion date. My question is is there a way to remove records based on this partition_ID if there's not an option of the pseudo column based on load date.

Comment: The partition ID is simply the value of the partition. No relation of the date of ingestion or the source file. 2 row, in the same partition, and ingested at different time will have the same partition ID